# Date not displayed as expected

Tags: javascript, cypress

i have this code:

```
const mydate = Cypress.dayjs('07 / 12')
cy.get('.dateOptions').contains('July 2017').click()
cy.get('.display').should('contain', mydate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

My question is that why the date is displaying 12/07/2001 instead of 12/07/2017
the error is:
expected  to contain 12/07/2001

Comment: What is the date you see in your display.

Comment: In my display i see 12/07/2017

Comment: Have you tried adding a year to your `mydate` variable? `Cypress.dayjs('07 / 12 / 2017')`?

Comment: It is displayed correctly when i add the year to the variable but when i do it by selecting the month in the dropdown it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the year also it seems. It should be changed to `const mydate = Cypress.dayjs('07/12/2017')`.

Test:

```js
const dayjs = require('dayjs')

describe('test suite', () => {

    it('Test', () => {
        const date = dayjs('07/12/2022').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
        cy.log(date)
    })
})
```

Test Runner screenshot:

[image: test runner screenshot]

Comment: But this is not how my steps work also why 2001?

Comment: 2001 is most likely the default year that `dayjs` uses when a year is not provided.